# function of catchup api on airflow?

Tags: api, airflow

i was searched about catchup on [airflow documentatuon](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#api-reference-operators).

but i still don't understand what the purpose of this API.

> catchup (bool) – Perform scheduler catchup (or only run latest)? Defaults to True

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find an expanded explanation in the [documents about scheduling backfill and catchup](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html?highlight=catchup#backfill-and-catchup).

Let me try to expand on it with an example.

Assume this calendar for January this year:

```
    January 2018
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31
```

Let's say you add a DAG on the 23rd with `start_date=datetime(2018, 1, 1)` and `schedule_interval='0 0 * * MON'`.

With `catchup=True` on first parsing the DAG the scheduler will immediately recognize that the periods 1-1 to 1-8, 1-8 to 1-15, 1-15 to 1-22 have closed and passed. It would schedule a DAG run for `execution_date` `2018-01-01` starting when you add the DAG on 23rd. If there are `max_active_runs > 2` it would also schedule a DAG run for `2018-01-08` and `2018-01-15`.

With `catchup=False` on first parsing the DAG the scheduler will still recognize that the same periods have closed and passed. But it would schedule a DAG run for `execution_date` `2018-01-15` only, starting when you add the DAG on 23rd. IE it would run the most recent closed period first, and not run any prior periods. The next run would then be `2018-01-22` starting at `2018-01-29T00:00:00±scheduler_lag`. But if after the `2018-01-15` run completed, you paused the DAG, and then unpaused it on `2018-01-29T09:00`, the scheduler would see that there are prior dag runs, and that the most recent period's start time is well past, it would not run a catchup run of this missed period.